# How to convert given input Array to output Array in O(n) without using adding and division operations?

Tags: javascript

Find the relation between input array and output array from below samples.

```
   Input Array                                     Output Array
  -------------                                 -----------------
  [10,20,30,40,50,60]       ------->    [72000000,36000000,24000000,18000000,14400000,12000000]
  [1,5,7,4,3,4,5]           ------->            [8400,1680,1200,2100,2800,2100,1680]
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be asking us that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be:

```
function calculate(arr) {
  let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => a * c, 1);
  return arr.map((n) => divide(result, n));
}

function divide(numerator, denominator) {
  let division;
  // return numerator / denominator;
  // You should write the algorithm
  return division;
}
```